# different web.config settings for http and https

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Is it possible to configure your web.config file of your asp.net website to use different settings for users accessing the site via HTTPS?

(eg. I need to have validateRequest attribute for https access set to false, but for internal access (using http) set to true...)

thanks!

Comment: What's the point of offering the same site on http and https together?  Why not just use https for internal as well as external?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable request validation in the Web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <pages validateRequest="false"/>
</system.web>
```

And in the Global.asax file, add an event handler for BeginRequest along the lines of:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    public override Init()
    {
        base.Init();
        BeginRequest += ToggleValidation;
    }

    void ToggleValidation(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsSecureConnection)
            Request.ValidateInput();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, I would recommend deploying internal and extenal sites a different sites altogether. That means you could use windows authentication internally and forms authentication externally, and change whatever other config settings you desire. It also means you can limit the attack surface for external evil-doers by not providing access to methods intended for internal users only.

Comment: I agree. If you have the ability to identify internal and external at the network level then do so. Break the site in two, have a common library between them both so you reduce code duplication. In answer to your question though, no, you cannot have a differing web.config on a single site because with every change the application is restarted